# Alfresco и CIFS через kerberos

Tags: java, active-directory, alfresco

Доборго дня!

Столкнулся с проблемой настройки (точнее, восстановлении работоспособности) авторизации при монтировании диска Alfresco в AD через kerberos.
Предыстория (короткая):
была поставлена задача перенести серверы в отдельную подсеть. Задача была выполнена, соответственно, сменились ip-адреса, шлюзы и тому подобное. С этого момента начались проблемы с Alfresco - не удается зайти на сетевой диск Alfresco, запрашивается логин/пароль.
Поскольку конфиги там довольно обширные, выложу только то, что, как мне кажется, относится к делу. А если понадобится, предоставлю любую информацию.

Итак, начну.
Исходные данные:
1. Сервер - Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
2. Alfresco 4.2.f
3. Контроллеры домена - WinServer 2012R2

В Active Directory созданы для Alfresco пользователи-службы (cifs и http), их настройки сделаны в соответствии с мануалами и вики.
На сервере Ubuntu настроил kerberos, проверил утилитой kinit как на рядовом пользователе, так и на пользователях-службах Alfresco с использованием keytab'ов - отрабатывает без ошибок. Из этого делаю вывод, что настройки в krb5.conf корректны.
Далее конфиги Alfresco, относящиеся к Kerberos и CIFS.
**alfresco-global.properties**

```
authentication.chain=kerberos1:kerberos,ldap1:ldap,alfrescoNtlm1:alfrescoNtlm    

### Kerberos and CIFS properties ###
kerberos.authentication.sso.enabled=true
kerberos.authentication.defaultAdministratorUserNames=<username>
kerberos.authentication.user.configEntryName=Alfresco
kerberos.authentication.cifs.configEntryName=AlfrescoCIFS
kerberos.authentication.cifs.password=************
kerberos.authentication.http.configEntryName=AlfrescoHTTP
kerberos.authentication.http.password=************
kerberos.authentication.authenticateCIFS=true
kerberos.authentication.realm=MY.DOMAIN.COM
kerberos.authentication.stripUsernameSuffix=true
```

**kerberos-authentication.properties**

```
kerberos.authentication.realm=MY.DOMAIN.COM
kerberos.authentication.user.configEntryName=Alfresco
kerberos.authentication.cifs.configEntryName=AlfrescoCIFS
kerberos.authentication.cifs.password=************
kerberos.authentication.authenticateCIFS=true
```

**kerberos-filter.properties**

```
kerberos.authentication.sso.enabled=true
kerberos.authentication.http.configEntryName=AlfrescoHTTP
kerberos.authentication.http.password=************
kerberos.authentication.browser.ticketLogons=true
```

**java.login.config**

```
Alfresco {
   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule sufficient;
};

AlfrescoCIFS {
   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
   storeKey=true
   useKeyTab=true
   keyTab="/opt/alfresco-4.2.f/server1cifs.keytab"
   principal="cifs/server1.my.domain.com";
};

AlfrescoHTTP {
   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
   storeKey=true
   useKeyTab=true
   keyTab="/opt/alfresco-4.2.f/server1http.keytab"
   principal="HTTP/server1.my.domain.com.com";
};

com.sun.net.ssl.client {
   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule sufficient;
};

other {
   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule sufficient;
};
```

При старте Alfresco в логе вижу следующее:

> 12:06:38,688 WARN 
>   [org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory]
>   Startup of 'Authentication' subsystem, ID: [Authentication, managed,
>   kerberos1] failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'cifsAuthenticator' defined in file
>   [/opt/alfresco-4.2.f/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/subsystems/Authentication/kerberos/kerberos-authentication-context.xml]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.SecurityException: Configuration Error:     Can not specify
>   multiple entries for Alfresco

Содержимое **kerberos-authentication-context.xml** на который ссылка в ошибке:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC '-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN' 'http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd'>

<beans>
   <!-- The authentication component.                                      -->

   <!-- Jass authentication - most of the config goes somewhere else       -->

   <bean id="authenticationComponent" class="org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.jaas.JAASAuthenticationComponent"
      parent="authenticationComponentBase">
      <property name="realm">
         <value>${kerberos.authentication.realm}</value>
      </property>
      <property name="jaasConfigEntryName">
         <value>${kerberos.authentication.user.configEntryName}</value>
      </property>
      <property name="nodeService">
         <ref bean="nodeService" />
      </property>
      <property name="personService">
         <ref bean="personService" />
      </property>
      <property name="transactionService">
         <ref bean="transactionService" />
      </property>
      <property name="defaultAdministratorUserNameList">
         <value>${kerberos.authentication.defaultAdministratorUserNames}</value>
      </property>
   </bean>

   <!-- Wrapped version to be used within subsystem -->
   <bean id="AuthenticationComponent" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
      <property name="proxyInterfaces">
         <value>org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationComponent</value>
      </property>
      <property name="transactionManager">
         <ref bean="transactionManager" />
      </property>
      <property name="target">
         <ref bean="authenticationComponent" />
      </property>
      <property name="transactionAttributes">
         <props>
            <prop key="*">${server.transaction.mode.default}</prop>
         </props>
      </property>
   </bean>

   <!-- Authenticaton service for chaining -->
   <bean id="localAuthenticationService" class="org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceImpl">
      <property name="ticketComponent">
         <ref bean="ticketComponent" />
      </property>
      <property name="authenticationComponent">
         <ref bean="authenticationComponent" />
      </property>
      <property name="sysAdminParams">
         <ref bean="sysAdminParams" />
      </property>
   </bean>

   <!-- CIFS authentication -->
   <bean id="cifsAuthenticator" class="org.alfresco.filesys.auth.cifs.EnterpriseCifsAuthenticator" parent="cifsAuthenticatorBase">
      <property name="active">
         <value>${kerberos.authentication.authenticateCIFS}</value>
      </property>
      <property name="realm">
         <value>${kerberos.authentication.realm}</value>
      </property>
      <property name="password">
         <value>${kerberos.authentication.cifs.password}</value>
      </property>
      <property name="jaasConfigEntryName">
         <value>${kerberos.authentication.cifs.configEntryName}</value>
      </property>
      <property name="disableNTLM">
         <value>true</value>
      </property>
      <property name="enableTicketCracking">
         <value>${kerberos.authentication.cifs.enableTicketCracking}</value>
      </property>
      <property name="stripKerberosUsernameSuffix">
         <value>${kerberos.authentication.stripUsernameSuffix}</value>
      </property>
   </bean>

</beans>
```

Вот такая вот загогулина...Учитывая, что ничего, кроме ip-адресов серверов не менялось, ума не приложу, что пошло не так.
К слову сказать, контроллеры домена пингуются с сервера Alfresco и по ip, и по NETBIOS-имени, и по FQDN.